# The safest and fastest way to upload files in Docker Container

Tags: linux, file-upload, docker

In a docker project of Asp.net Core MVC 6.0, users must upload files to `wwwroot` of the project but nothing checks to see if the file is safe or not.

I check file extensions with my file header library but is this enough?

When I searched the internet, I saw that antiviruses must not access the container. If scanned, [the container may hang](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/antivirus/).

I am running a multi-vendor system and users upload images and their files come to the front-end

Before, in my friend project a hacker upload virus file with `png` extension but after some time host antivirus find it.

My problem is how prevent this harmful files to upload in my container when container is isolated ?

Check the file header is enough or not?

How can i access antivirus to file upload folder?

What is the best way?

Comment: I tried to make sense of your "antivirus" line. Can you phrase or try another way of stating it? Does my edit say what you wanted to say? If the link I added is what you are concerned about, one option is to install an antivirus ***in*** the container.

Comment: Safe against *what*?

Comment: @vidarlo , harmful files like `queries` or `macros`

Comment: It's not possible to answer without knowing what the data is used for. One way to secure things is to ensure that you don't execute the content of uploaded files. It all depends on the application.

Comment: @vidarlo , I am running a multi-vendor system and users upload images and their files come to the front-end

Comment: @schroeder , you are right but i don't find good images for that. Is it possible to introduce a reliable image?

Comment: Queries and macros are not files ... you can install an antivirus into the container. You could expose the file upload location to an external antivirus on the host, you can upload the files to a external or 3rd party service. There are tons of ways to scan files in your situation, but we're having trouble understanding your set up or what the security issues are.

Comment: You want to ensure that the image files uploaded by your users are "safe". Ok, what are you worried about? What could an image do? How are images processed by your system?

Comment: @schroeder , I check the extension with file header any way in your idea is enough ?

Comment: @schroeder Thank you very much. You have given me enough idea to solve the problem. Please answer it so that it can be accepted and other users can see it better.

Comment: @mamad2559 It entirely depends on how you process the data. There is no panacea; [Evil Bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_bit) didn't catch on.

Comment: @vidarlo , Thank you for your sincere help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand what you're trying to achieve here, you have an application running in a container which processes untrusted files and you'd like to be able to scan the images to ensure they are not malicious before processing.

Should you want to use host based anti-virus for this, one way of doing it would be to put the images in a directory on the host, and mount that directory into the container (e.g. using the `-v` switch on Docker), then have the anti-virus solution scan that directory instead of the whole container (this should avoid Docker's concerns with regards to scanning containers on a host).